# Page loading is gradually getting slower using jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, loading, delay

I'm using this jQuery script to show search results. Everything works fine, but when search results have more than one page and I'm browsing pages via paging then every page loading is gradually getting slower. Usually first cca 10 pages loads I get quickly, but next are getting avoiding loading delay. Whole website get frozen for a little while (also loader image), but browser is not yet. What should be the problem?

```
function editResults(def) {
    $('.searchResults').html('<p class=\'loader\'><img src=\'images/loader.gif\' /></p>');
    var url = def;
    var url = url + "&categories=";
    // Parse Categories
    $('input[name=chCat[]]').each(function() {    
        if (this.checked == true) {
            url = url + this.value + ",";
        }
    });
    url = url + "&sizes=";
    // Parse Sizes
    $('input[name=chSize[]]').each(function() {    
        if (this.checked == true) {
            url = url + this.value + ",";
        }
    }); 
    url = url + "&prices=";
    // Parse Prices
    $('input[name=chPrice[]]').each(function() {    
        if (this.checked == true) {
            url = url + this.value + ",";
        }
    });
    $('.searchResults').load('results.php'+url);
    $('.pageLinks').live("click", function() {
        var page = this.title; 
        editResults("?page="+page);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    editResults("?page=1");
    // Check All Categories
    $('input[name=chCat[0]]').click(function() {
        check_status = $('input[name=chCat[0]]').attr("checked");
        $('input[name=chCat[]]').each(function() {    
            this.checked = check_status;    
        });
    });
    // Check All Sizes
    $('input[name=chSize[0]]').click(function() {
        check_status = $('input[name=chSize[0]]').attr("checked");
        $('input[name=chSize[]]').each(function() {    
            this.checked = check_status;    
        });
    });
    // Edit Results
    $('.checkbox').change(function() {
        editResults("?page=1");
    });
    // Change Type
   $(".sort").change(function() {               
        editResults("?page=1&sort="+$(this).val());
   });          
});
```

Comment: Are the server responses possibly get slower and slower to come back?  It is fairly typical that getting the xth page gets slower as x increases, because more records have to be traversed in the database.  You could validate this by printing out timing results on your server-side page, or by capturing timing results with a tool like [**Fiddler**](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you for your explanation, but what exactly do you mean about printing out timing results on my server-side page?

Comment: NOTE: `.live()` has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and has been removed in 1.9. It is recommended you switch to the newer `.on()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.pageLinks').live("click", function() {
    var page = this.title; 
    editResults("?page="+page);
});
```

just a wild guess but... wouldn't this piece of code add a new event handler to the click event instead reaplacing the old one with a new one? causing the click to call all the once registered handlers.

you should make the event binding just once

```
var global_var = '1';

function editResults(def) {
    // all your code
    global_var = 2; // what ever page goes next
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    // all your code ...
    $('.pageLinks').live("click", function() {
        var page = global_var;
        editResults("?page="+page);
    });
});
```

Comment: This whole script works only with jQuery 1.4 or older. I tried to replace `.live()` with newer `.on()` but nothing happened after click.

`$(document).on("click",".pageLinks",function(){
    var page = this.title; 
    editResults("?page="+page);
   });`

Comment: the problem is not related on what method are you calling. In this regard _live_ and _on_ works the same. Every time you call _editResults_ your element(s) _pageLinks_ gets a new event handler, not removing the old one(s).

Comment: So how should I make the event binding just once?

Comment: I've edited my response with a very rusty example of what I mean.